Can air velocity be supersonic in a straight pipe?
Consider a sufficiently large reservoir of compressed air at a pressure of $7 \text{ bar}$ (abs.). A tapping of $25 \text{mm}$ diameter of pipe length $1 \text { m}$. The pipe is open to the atmosphere on one end.
Applying Bernoulli's theorem between point 1 (inside the reservoir) and point $2$ (just at the outlet of the pipe), we get,
$$P_1 = P_2 +\frac12\rho v^2$$
Where $v$ is the velocity at the exit of the pipe.
Taking $P_1$ as $700000 \text{ Pa}$ and $P_2$ as $100000 \text{ Pa}$, density of compressed air as $8.4$ $\text{ kg/}$$m^3$, we get
$v = 377 \text{ m/s}$.
(I am neglecting the friction losses, entry and exit losses as I want a rough estimate)
Is this calculation correct? Where am I making a mistake? Can the velocity reach supersonic without the use of a converging-diverging duct?

So not worth accepting the answer?

@Solar Mike Done
